# Google Drive SDK: To copy files from a user to another user via Domain Super Administrator access right

Tags: google-drive-api

Say, I am a Domain Super Administrator. And, there are User A (source - files to be copied from) and User B (destination - files to be copied to). Is there any Google Drive SDK API available for this feature?

When I read this: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy, this API allows only to copy into my own Google Drive.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use domain-wide delegation to impersonate each user https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation.
2. Authenticate as source user and share file with target user https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert
3. Authenticate as target user and copy source file to produce target copy of file owned by target user https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy

Comment: What about if you want to copy shared file outside your domain, is it possible?