# Backup google drive to another google drive account

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, sails.js, drive

I am working on an application where I have to create whole google drive backup to another google drive on daily basis. I am able to authenticate with google drive and also able to list the file and folder. I added the separate account where the backup will be done. Now can you guys suggest how I should proceed further?

Should I share every file to another account and copy that file to drive or do you guys suggest anything else?  Please suggest.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

I think this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14126773) is a good suggestion.

> 1. Use domain-wide delegation to impersonate each user https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation.
> 2. Authenticate as source user and share file with target user https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert
> 3. Authenticate as target user and copy source file to produce target copy of file owned by target user
>      https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy